# $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4}) $ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4}i) $?

Tags: galois-theory

I need to show that $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4}) $ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4}i) $.
My issue is showing $2^{1/4}i $ is in $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4}) $. I dont see how there could be an imaginary part in $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4}) $.

Comment: $Q(r)$ indeed doesn't comtain imaginary numbers for a real $r$. "Isomorphic" doesn't mean "equal".

Comment: @Surb: That's not true. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$, but both are quadratic extensions over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 5):

Showing that two subfields of $ \mathbb C $ are isomorphic is not the same thing as showing that they are *equal*. Indeed, $ \mathbb Q(2^{1/4}) \neq \mathbb Q(2^{1/4} i) $ as subfields of $ \mathbb C $, but they are nevertheless isomorphic.

**Hint:** Use the result that if $ f $ is the minimal polynomial of $ a $ over some field $ F $, where $ a $ lies in a field extension $ E/F $, then $ F[x]/(f) \cong F(a) $.